# Creating a searchable archive using tags

Tags: 2013, search

I've been tasked with creating a archive at work where we can search through the documents using parameters given in the forms of tags.

To give an example to better illustrate what I am working towards:

CompanyX handles 10000 cases a year. 50 of these were rather troublesome and required quite some time to process. Because of this, CompanyX wants to store these so that they can be used as references should a similar case happen. Each file should be then be tagged with certain keywords so that they can easily be found at a later date.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be much appricated!

Comment: Is not possible with SharePoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using metadata navigation on a document library.  Enable the metadata navigation and filtering site feature, then create a document library and add a managed metadata column to it. Populate the column's terms with appropriate values (such as Troublesome Case) and then add the column to your metadata navigation.

[YouTube walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqt99a6fEXU)

Tagging in this way also empowers SharePoint search.